# if clause in html with CSS tag max-device-width, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, uiwebview

I have an **Universal iOS Project** and in this project I have to display in a UIWebView some locally stored html pages.

To resize the html content I have to use in the html the tag:

```
<meta name ="viewport" content = "width = 703, user-scalable=no "> \\for the iPad
```

and

```
<meta name ="viewport" content = "width = device-width, user-scalable=no "> \\for the iPhone
```

Is there a way to add in the html's header something like:

```
if( max-device-width == 480) {
     <meta name ="viewport" content = "width = device-width, user-scalable=no ">
}
else {
   <meta name ="viewport" content = "width = 703, user-scalable=no ">
}
```

Is there a way to do this in HTML or JS? I have only elementary notions about html and js so any help to achieve this would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You should read http://quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html along with other articles on the Quirksmode site. He's got a lot of info on how to deal with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to query the window size (though you have to be careful, [see this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow)) and replace the width value with the value that you obtain from the JavaScript result.  Do read the quirksmode post mentioned above.  [If you're really worried about the result, you may consider using a javascript library like jQuery, which should handle all of the browser cases for you.]  The "user-scalable=no" can just be appended to the value you set content.